# LibreOffice Calc: Merging cells with Borders, removing the right side of the borders

Tags: libreoffice-calc

While using the border feature in the LibreOffice Calc, its working fine. But when I'm merging the the cells inside a cell which has borders, it removing the right side of the borders. Please look at the screenshots:
[image]

1. Simply merged few cells.
2. Added borders to the cell after merging.
3. Here after applying the merge option to a bordered cell, see that the border of right side of the box disappears.

Whats happening here? I need a solution in which the right side of the border did not disappears. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set all borders before merging, not just the outside borders:

[image: outside and inside borders]

If the first unmerged cell does not have a bottom or right border, then neither will the merged cell:

[image: outside borders only]

**EDIT**:

To make it easier to perform this action repeatedly, I recorded the following macro.  It could be assigned to a hotkey or toolbar button via `Tools -> Customize`.

```vb
sub SetAllBordersAndMerge
    dim document   as object
    dim dispatcher as object
    document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
    dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

    dim args1(12) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    args1(0).Name = "OuterBorder.LeftBorder"
    args1(0).Value = Array(0,0,2,0,0,2)
    args1(1).Name = "OuterBorder.LeftDistance"
    args1(1).Value = 0
    args1(2).Name = "OuterBorder.RightBorder"
    args1(2).Value = Array(0,0,2,0,0,2)
    args1(3).Name = "OuterBorder.RightDistance"
    args1(3).Value = 0
    args1(4).Name = "OuterBorder.TopBorder"
    args1(4).Value = Array(0,0,2,0,0,2)
    args1(5).Name = "OuterBorder.TopDistance"
    args1(5).Value = 0
    args1(6).Name = "OuterBorder.BottomBorder"
    args1(6).Value = Array(0,0,2,0,0,2)
    args1(7).Name = "OuterBorder.BottomDistance"
    args1(7).Value = 0
    args1(8).Name = "InnerBorder.Horizontal"
    args1(8).Value = Array(0,0,2,0,0,2)
    args1(9).Name = "InnerBorder.Vertical"
    args1(9).Value = Array(0,0,2,0,0,2)
    args1(10).Name = "InnerBorder.Flags"
    args1(10).Value = 0
    args1(11).Name = "InnerBorder.ValidFlags"
    args1(11).Value = 127
    args1(12).Name = "InnerBorder.DefaultDistance"
    args1(12).Value = 0
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:SetBorderStyle", "", 0, args1())

    dim args2(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    args2(0).Name = "MoveContents"
    args2(0).Value = true
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:ToggleMergeCells", "", 0, args2())
end sub
```

Comment: Yes, setting borders of all the cells before merging is working. But if I have to merge atleast 10 cells and there's hundreds of rows present, then you can understand the problem here. Is there any alternative? Thanks for your help.

Comment: See my edited answer above.  Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that helps. Thank you. I've assigned the macro to toolbar. It would have been great if you record the macro with maximum border thickness in Border Style. However thank you again.